# error on installing language-check packages to python 2.7 environment

Tags: python-2.7

I am having problem of installing python package language-check to my python 2.7 environment.

I tried the pip install language-check --upgrade command but it was no avail. It gave my error saying "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fn/g0nd0gb54d5c__5fjhb7rp0w0000gn/T/pip-build-zMuFbc/language-check/". I have problem of understanding what it is saying. If you know what it is saying, please give me a hint on how to fix it.

I also tried to download the laguage-check tar.gz to my mac, gunzip it, ran tar -xwf command on it, went to language-check directory and ran setup install but it did not work either . It gave me an error saying "error in language-check setup command: package_data must be a dictionary mapping package names to lists of wildcard patterns". So if you know how to fix the problem, please let me know.

Thank you so much in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

I found alternative: `pip install --user --upgrade grammar-check`